# Error code 610 backing up DB2 to TSM

Tags: db2, tivoli, tsm

I'm trying to back up a DB2 database using Tivoli Storage Manager (TSM), but it's erroring out.

I'm now getting this error message:

```
[db2inst1@hostname ~]$ export DSMI_CONFIG=/etc/adsm/dsm.opt
[db2inst1@hostname ~]$ export DSMI_LOG=/home/db2inst1
[db2inst1@hostname ~]$ export DSMI_DIR=/opt/tivoli/tsm/client/api/bin64

[db2inst1@hostname ~]$ db2 BACKUP DB foo ONLINE USE TSM OPTIONS @/etc/adsm/dsm.opt
SQL2033N  An error occurred while accessing TSM during the processing of a
database utility.  TSM reason code: "610".

[db2inst1@hostname ~]$ db2 BACKUP DB foo ONLINE USE TSM
SQL2033N  An error occurred while accessing TSM during the processing of a
database utility.  TSM reason code: "610"
```

Backing up the database to a regular file works.

According to dsmrc.h, this is error code 610:

```
#define DSM_RC_NLS_CANT_OPEN_TXT   610 /* error trying to open msg txt file  */
```

I don't know why it would be able to find the messages txt.

Here's my /etc/adsm/dsm.sys file:

```
* Servername corresponds with value given in dsm.opt
    SERVERname         TSM_SERVER

* Note: if you previously had a windows node, you cannot reuse the
* same node name and must apply for a new one for your linux backups
    NODENAME           foo-db
    TCPServeraddress   some.tsm.server.com
    TCPPort            1500
    QUERYSCHEDPERIOD   3
    COMMmethod         TCPIP

    PASSWORDAccess     Generate
    SCHEDMode          Polling
    SCHEDLOGName       /var/log/tsm/dsmsched.log
    SCHEDLOGRetention  7 D
    ERRORLOGName       /var/log/tsm/dsmerror.log
    ERRORLOGRetention  7 D
    INCLEXCL          /opt/tivoli/tsm/client/ba/bin/inclexcl
    COMPRESSION        No
    ManagedService     schedule

* Space separated list of users requiring TSM access (case sensitive).
    USERS              root db2inst1

* Virtualmountpoints allow you to specifiy a path as a domain to be backed up
* in dsm.opt, without it being on its own filesystem.
* If any of these paths are on their own filesystem remove the entry here.
    VIRTUALMOUNTPoint  /home
    VIRTUALMOUNTPoint  /root
    VIRTUALMOUNTPoint  /etc
    VIRTUALMOUNTPoint  /var/www
```

Here's my /etc/adsm/dsm.opt file:

```
  SERVERNAME      TSM_SERVER
  COMPRESSAlways  No
  DATEformat      3
  LANGuage        AMENG

* Add domains (filesystems) eligible for backup.
* If you want to specifiy a domain that isn't on its own filesystem
* you will need to add a virtualmountpoint entry for it in dsm.sys

  DOMAIN "/home"
  DOMAIN "/root"
  DOMAIN "/etc"
  DOMAIN "/var/www"
```

Here's some diagnostic info:

```
[db2inst1@hostname db2dump]$ db2level
DB21085I  Instance "db2inst1" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10010"
with level identifier "0201010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.1.0.0", "s120211", "LINUXAMD64101", and Fix
Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V10.1".

[db2inst1@hostname db2dump]$ db2licm -l
Product name:                     "DB2 Enterprise Server Edition"
License type:                     "CPU Option"
Expiry date:                      "Permanent"
Product identifier:               "db2ese"
Version information:              "10.1"
Enforcement policy:               "Soft Stop"
Features:
DB2 Performance Optimization ESE: "Not licensed"
DB2 Storage Optimization:         "Not licensed"
DB2 Advanced Access Control:      "Not licensed"
DB2 Geodetic Data Management:     "Not licensed"
IBM Homogeneous Replication ESE:  "Not licensed"
DB2 pureCluster:                  "Not licensed"



[db2inst1@hostname db2dump]$ uname -a
Linux hostname 2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 5 21:08:58 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[db2inst1@hostname db2dump]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.3 (Santiago)

[root@hostname bin64]# ls -la /opt/tivoli/tsm/client/api/bin64
total 165988
drwxr-xr-x 4 root bin       4096 Mar 22 12:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root bin       4096 Mar 22 11:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 root bin       4096 Mar 22 11:05 cit
-r--r--r-- 1 root bin        782 Jan  9 03:46 dsm.opt.smp
-r--r--r-- 1 root bin        971 Jan  9 03:46 dsm.sys.smp
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root bin    7060424 Jan  9 03:46 dsmtca
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 Mar 22 11:05 EN_US -> ../../lang/EN_US
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin    8805328 Jan  9 03:46 libApiTSM64.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin    1555256 Jan  9 03:46 libcrypto.so.0.9.8
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin      36404 Jan  9 03:46 libdmapi.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin      50183 Jan  9 03:46 libgpfs.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin     325912 Jan  9 03:46 libssl.so.0.9.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root bin         14 Mar 22 11:05 libTsmViSdkAPI.so -> libTsmViSdk.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin  148796471 Jan  9 03:46 libTsmViSdk.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root bin         18 Mar 22 11:05 libVMcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.0.9.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root bin         15 Mar 22 11:05 libVMssl.so -> libssl.so.0.9.8
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin    2984648 Jan  9 03:46 libxerces-c1_6_0.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin     117659 Jan  9 03:46 libxmlutil-6.4.0.0.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 Mar 22 11:05 RU_RU -> ../../lang/RU_RU
drwxr-xr-x 2 root bin       4096 Mar 22 11:05 sample
```

Any thoughts on how I could work around error SQL2033N reason code 610? All the resources online seem to tell me to point DSMI_DIR somewhere else, but I don't know where else to point it to. Pointing it at the EN_US directory instead didn't help.

Comment: I sat down with a Tivoli expert to resolve this. I do not have the specifics as this was some time ago, but it involved make symbolic links to my .opt and .sys in Tivoli's bin64 directory.